# Is one bundled css used for all sub sites good?

Tags: css, node.js, webpack, sass, sass-loader

I recently started with node.js things. Discovered webpack and sass-loader, read about them. I think I got it all but one thing is bothering me.
When sass-loader bundles all my scss files to one - css, am I suposed to use this exactly file on all sub sites? Am guessing thats wrong so what am I suposed to do in big, multiple sites app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using one big CSS file is considered good. When people visit your site, the whole CSS will be cached, which allows the subpages to load much faster.